# Why does "git stash pop" right after "git stash --keep-index" result in conflicts?

Tags: git, git-stash

I did:

```
$ git stash --keep-index
$ git stash pop
```

and Git asks me to solve conflicts.

Do I do something wrong? How can I stash unstaged files (test the programm) and then return everything back (so I've got all staged files untouched and unstaged files are back and are unstaged)?

Comment: Why do you use `--keep-index` ?

Comment: @Claudio, To test the program with only stashed changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the `--keep-index`. The changes you stashed are in conflicts with the changes you already staged.

Here are commands you can use to reproduce

```
echo bar > foo
git add foo
echo baz > foo
git stash --keep-index
git stash pop #CONFLICT
```

In that case git doesn't know whether bar or baz should be present in foo...

The solution would be not to use the `--keep-index` argument or to commit the changes you added first (you can always amend your commit later)

You can also get your working directory in the same state that before using `git stash branch <branchname>` (you will then have to merge the branch)

Comment: So git stash --keep-index stashes changes relative to the repository, not to the stage area? These stashed changes will include both, unstaged and staged changes, right?

Comment: There is no conflict with that example.

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` saves the transition from the HEAD state to the working tree state. It also sets the working tree to the *HEAD* state.

`git stash --keep-index` saves the transition from the HEAD state to the working tree state. It also sets the working tree to the *index* state.

`git stash pop` applies the last saved transition. So if the working tree was not in the HEAD state (like after staging changes to the index and executing `git stash --keep-index`), there may be a conflict. You can execute `git reset --hard` to set the working tree to the HEAD state before executing `git stash pop` to avoid it.